# How to remove the error "environment frontmatter undefined, \begin{frontmatter}"?

Tags: errors, compilation-error, front-matter

I use this code

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsxtra,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{color,colordvi}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}


\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{title}

\author[1]{author}
\ead{email}
\address[1]{address}


\begin{abstract}
Blah Blah
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\texttt{math, math}
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
```

and I get this error

**environment frontmatter undefined, \begin{frontmatter}?**

I will be grateful if tell me where I am going wrong and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. frontmatter is simply not defined in an article document.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks :) It worked.

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @Hack-R I think replacing  "article" by "elsearticle" in \documentclass.